# Show the solution of this ODE has to be the trivial one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Let $f$ be continuous in $\Omega=\{(t,x);|t|\leq a,|x|\leq b\}$. If
>   $f(t,x)\lt 0$ when $tx\gt0$ and $f(t,x)\gt 0$ when $tx\lt0$. Show that $x'=f(t,x), x(0)=0$ has $\varphi=0$ as the unique solution.

I'm completely confused with this question, $x$ is a function or a variable?

I need a hint to begin to solve this question.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Youler's answer:

Assume we have a nonzero solution and $t^*>0$ is a point in which $\phi(t^*)>0$. By assumption this implies $\phi^\prime=f<0$ at $t^*$.

Observe $\phi$ is continuous, since $\phi(t)=\phi(t)-\phi(0)=\int_0^t f(\phi(s),s)\, ds.$

Select $m=\sup \{x<t^* : \phi(x)=0\}$. This exists and is less than $t^*$, otherwise we may select an $x_n\in (t-\frac{1}{n},t)$ such that $\phi(x_n)=0$. Due to continuity, $$0=\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi(x_n)=\phi(t^*)>0$$
which is a contradiction.

Without loss of generality allow $m=0$.
So, by the mean value theorem, there exists a $c\in(0,t^*)$ such that 
$$\phi(t^*)-\phi(0)=\phi^{\prime}(c)(t^*-0),$$
which is a contradiction because the left side is positive and the right is negative. Do the other cases similarly.

Comment: This does not seem quite logically complete to me since it could a priori be that, say, $\varphi(t)$ looks like $-\sin t$ and that $c$ is in the initial region where $\varphi$ is negative.

Comment: An argument to fix would just be that $\varphi$ can not change sign, since then by the mean value theorem applied to $\varphi(0)=0$ and $\varphi(T)=0$ there is a point where $\varphi'=0$ and $\varphi$ is nonzero, a contradiction to what we know about $f.$

Comment: Equally well there's the argument sketched in my comment on my earlier answer, although in retrospect perhaps that's overcomplicated.

Comment: You're right, I corrected my answer. I wrote mine without seeing yours. The end idea is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here $x$ is a function of $t$, so e.g. the ODE, written more explicitly, is
$$x'(t)=f\big(t,x(t)\big).$$
To be clear, both sides are functions of $t.$

Here's a hint: suppose instead that $\varphi=0$ is not the unique solution, so that there's a nonzero function $\varphi$ with $\varphi'(t)=f(t,\varphi(t))$ and $\varphi(0)=0.$ Since we're supposing that $\varphi$ is not identically zero, it has to be nonzero somewhere, say at $t^\ast>0$ we have $\varphi(t^\ast)>0$ (but also consider separately the case $\varphi(t^\ast)<0$). From what we know about $f$, we have $\varphi'(t^\ast)<0.$ So in summary, we have a function $\varphi$ which is positive somewhere and is decreasing whenever it is positive. Try to show then that in such a scenario we can't also have $\varphi(0)=0.$

Comment: Intuitively speaking I can see this, the difficulty is to prove formally.

Comment: Consider the infimum value $t_\ast$ of $t$ such that $\varphi(t)>0$, so that $\varphi(t_\ast)=0$. Let $\delta>0$ be such that $\varphi$ is positive on $(t_\ast,t_\ast+2\delta).$ Then as we've established now, $\varphi$ is (strictly) decreasing on this interval. So for any $t\in(t_\ast,t_\ast+\delta)$, we have $\varphi(t)>\varphi(t_\ast+\delta)>0.$ In particular we cannot have $\varphi(t)\to 0$ as $t\to t_\ast.$